# Hyperledger Fabric Error on Creating channel

Tags: docker, networking, yaml, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I'm setting up a Hyperledger Fabric network and encountering an error when trying to connect to the orderer. The error message I'm getting is:

```
Error: failed to create deliver client for orderer: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.trackandtrace.com:7050: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp 45.35.38.138:7050: connect: connection refused"
```

It happens when i try to execute the following command:

```
peer channel create -o orderer.trackandtrace.com:7050 -c mychannel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls true --cafile crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/trackandtrace.com/orderers/orderer.trackandtrace.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.trackandtrace.com-cert.pem
```

I have 4 config files in my home dir: crypto-config.yaml, configtx.yaml, docker-compose.yaml and core.yaml. My docker containers are all running and i can also reach my orderer via telnet from inside the container.

configtx.yaml:

```html
---
Organizations:
    - &Orderer
        Name: Orderer
        ID: OrdererMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/trackandtrace.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"
        OrdererEndpoints:
            - orderer.example.com:7050        

    - &Consignor
        Name: ConsignorMSP
        ID: ConsignorMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/consignor.trackandtrace.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('ConsignorMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('ConsignorMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('ConsignorMSP.admin')"
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.consignor.trackandtrace.com
              Port: 7051
    - &Consignee
        Name: ConsigneeMSP
        ID: ConsigneeMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/consignee.trackandtrace.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('ConsigneeMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('ConsigneeMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('ConsigneeMSP.admin')"
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.consignee.trackandtrace.com
              Port: 7051

    - &PreCarriageShipper
        Name: PreCarriageShipperMSP
        ID: PreCarriageShipperMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/precarriageshipper.trackandtrace.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('PreCarriageShipperMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('PreCarriageShipperMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('PreCarriageShipperMSP.admin')"
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.precarriageshipper.trackandtrace.com
              Port: 7051

    - &MainCarrier
        Name: MainCarrierMSP
        ID: MainCarrierMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/maincarrier.trackandtrace.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('MainCarrierMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('MainCarrierMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('MainCarrierMSP.admin')"
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.maincarrier.trackandtrace.com
              Port: 7051

    - &OnCarriageShipper
        Name: OnCarriageShipperMSP
        ID: OnCarriageShipperMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/oncarriageshipper.trackandtrace.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OnCarriageShipperMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OnCarriageShipperMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OnCarriageShipperMSP.admin')"
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.oncarriageshipper.trackandtrace.com
              Port: 7051

    - &Customs
        Name: CustomsMSP
        ID: CustomsMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/customs.trackandtrace.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('CustomsMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('CustomsMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('CustomsMSP.admin')"
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.customs.trackandtrace.com
              Port: 7051

Capabilities:
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        V2_0: true
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        V2_0: true
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        V2_0: true

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    Organizations:
        - *Consignor
        - *Consignee
        - *PreCarriageShipper
        - *MainCarrier
        - *OnCarriageShipper
        - *Customs
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
    OrdererType: etcdraft
    EtcdRaft:
        Consenters:
            - Host: orderer.trackandtrace.com
              Port: 7050
              ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/trackandtrace.com/orderers/orderer.trackandtrace.com/tls/server.crt
              ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/trackandtrace.com/orderers/orderer.trackandtrace.com/tls/server.crt
    Addresses:
        - orderer.trackandtrace.com:7050
    Organizations:
        - *Orderer
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Capabilities:
        <<: *OrdererCapabilities

Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

Profiles:
    SampleMultiNodeEtcdRaft:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Orderer
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Consignor
                - *Consignee
                - *PreCarriageShipper
                - *MainCarrier
                - *OnCarriageShipper
                - *Customs
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Consignor
                    - *Consignee
                    - *PreCarriageShipper
                    - *MainCarrier
                    - *OnCarriageShipper
                    - *Customs

    Frachtverfolgung:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Consignor
                - *Consignee
                - *PreCarriageShipper
                - *MainCarrier
                - *OnCarriageShipper
                - *Customs
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "ANY Readers"
            Writers:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "ANY Writers"
            Admins:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
```

crypto-config.yaml:

```html
OrdererOrgs:
  - Name: Orderer
    Domain: trackandtrace.com
    Specs:
      - Hostname: orderer
PeerOrgs:
  - Name: Consignor
    Domain: consignor.trackandtrace.com
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1
  - Name: Consignee
    Domain: consignee.trackandtrace.com
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1
  - Name: PreCarriageShipper
    Domain: precarriageshipper.trackandtrace.com
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1
  - Name: MainCarrier
    Domain: maincarrier.trackandtrace.com
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1
  - Name: OnCarriageShipper
    Domain: oncarriageshipper.trackandtrace.com
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1
  - Name: Customs
    Domain: customs.trackandtrace.com
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```html
version: '2'

services:
  orderer.trackandtrace.com:
    container_name: orderer.trackandtrace.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer
    command: orderer
    volumes:
        - ./system-genesis-block/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/trackandtrace.com/orderers/orderer.trackandtrace.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/trackandtrace.com/orderers/orderer.trackandtrace.com/tls:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
    ports:
      - 7050:7050

  # Definieren Sie ähnliche Dienste für die Peers jeder Organisation. Sie können diesen Block kopieren und für jeden Peer anpassen.
  peer0.consignor.trackandtrace.com:
    container_name: peer0.consignor.trackandtrace.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.consignor.trackandtrace.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.consignor.trackandtrace.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.consignor.trackandtrace.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=ConsignorMSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/consignor.trackandtrace.com/peers/peer0.consignor.trackandtrace.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/consignor.trackandtrace.com/peers/peer0.consignor.trackandtrace.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    ports:
      - 7051:7051

  peer1.consignor.trackandtrace.com:
    container_name: peer1.consignor.trackandtrace.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.consignor.trackandtrace.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.consignor.trackandtrace.com:7052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.consignor.trackandtrace.com:7052
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=ConsignorMSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/consignor.trackandtrace.com/peers/peer1.consignor.trackandtrace.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/consignor.trackandtrace.com/peers/peer1.consignor.trackandtrace.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    ports:
      - 7052:7052    

  peer1.consignor.trackandtrace.com:
    container_name: peer1.consignor.trackandtrace.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.consignor.trackandtrace.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.consignor.trackandtrace.com:7052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.consignor.trackandtrace.com:7052
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=ConsignorMSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/consignor.trackandtrace.com/peers/peer1.consignor.trackandtrace.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/consignor.trackandtrace.com/peers/peer1.consignor.trackandtrace.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    ports:
      - 7052:7052    

  peer0.consignee.trackandtrace.com:
    container_name: peer0.consignee.trackandtrace.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.consignee.trackandtrace.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.consignee.trackandtrace.com:7053
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.consignee.trackandtrace.com:7053
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=ConsigneeMSP
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/consignee.trackandtrace.com/peers/peer0.consignee.trackandtrace.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/consignee.trackandtrace.com/peers/peer0.consignee.trackandtrace.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    ports:
      - 7053:7053

#(same for peer1 with port 7054)

  peer0.precarriageshipper.trackandtrace.com:
    container_name: peer0.precarriageshipper.trackandtrace.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.precarriageshipper.trackandtrace.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.precarriageshipper.trackandtrace.com:7055
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.precarriageshipper.trackandtrace.com:7055
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=PreCarriageShipperMSP
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/precarriageshipper.trackandtrace.com/peers/peer0.precarriageshipper.trackandtrace.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/precarriageshipper.trackandtrace.com/peers/peer0.precarriageshipper.trackandtrace.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    ports:
      - 7055:7055

#(same for peer1 with port 7056)

  peer0.maincarrier.trackandtrace.com:
    container_name: peer0.maincarrier.trackandtrace.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.maincarrier.trackandtrace.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.maincarrier.trackandtrace.com:7057
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.maincarrier.trackandtrace.com:7057
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=MainCarrierMSP
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/maincarrier.trackandtrace.com/peers/peer0.maincarrier.trackandtrace.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/maincarrier.trackandtrace.com/peers/peer0.maincarrier.trackandtrace.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    ports:
      - 7057:7057

#(same for peer1 with port 7058)

  peer0.oncarriageshipper.trackandtrace.com:
    container_name: peer0.oncarriageshipper.trackandtrace.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.oncarriageshipper.trackandtrace.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.oncarriageshipper.trackandtrace.com:7059
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.oncarriageshipper.trackandtrace.com:7059
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=OnCarriageShipperMSP
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/oncarriageshipper.trackandtrace.com/peers/peer0.oncarriageshipper.trackandtrace.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/oncarriageshipper.trackandtrace.com/peers/peer0.oncarriageshipper.trackandtrace.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    ports:
      - 7059:7059

#(same for peer1 with port 7060)

  peer0.customs.trackandtrace.com:
    container_name: peer0.customs.trackandtrace.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.customs.trackandtrace.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.customs.trackandtrace.com:7061
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.customs.trackandtrace.com:7061
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=CustomsMSP
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/customs.trackandtrace.com/peers/peer0.customs.trackandtrace.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/customs.trackandtrace.com/peers/peer0.customs.trackandtrace.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    ports:
      - 7061:7061

#(same for peer1 with port 7062)
```

core.yml:

```html
peer:
  id: jdoe
  networkId: dev
  listenAddress: '0.0.0.0:7051'
  address: '0.0.0.0:7051'
  addressAutoDetect: false
  gateway:
    enabled: true
    endorsementTimeout: 30s
    broadcastTimeout: 30s
    dialTimeout: 2m
  keepalive:
    interval: 7200s
    timeout: 20s
    minInterval: 60s
    client:
      interval: 60s
      timeout: 20s
    deliveryClient:
      interval: 60s
      timeout: 20s
  gossip:
    bootstrap: '127.0.0.1:7051'
    useLeaderElection: false
    orgLeader: true
    membershipTrackerInterval: 5s
    endpoint: null
    maxBlockCountToStore: 10
    maxPropagationBurstLatency: 10ms
    maxPropagationBurstSize: 10
    propagateIterations: 1
    propagatePeerNum: 3
    pullInterval: 4s
    pullPeerNum: 3
    requestStateInfoInterval: 4s
    publishStateInfoInterval: 4s
    stateInfoRetentionInterval: null
    publishCertPeriod: 10s
    skipBlockVerification: false
    dialTimeout: 3s
    connTimeout: 2s
    recvBuffSize: 20
    sendBuffSize: 200
    digestWaitTime: 1s
    requestWaitTime: 1500ms
    responseWaitTime: 2s
    aliveTimeInterval: 5s
    aliveExpirationTimeout: 25s
    reconnectInterval: 25s
    maxConnectionAttempts: 120
    msgExpirationFactor: 20
    externalEndpoint: null
    election:
      startupGracePeriod: 15s
      membershipSampleInterval: 1s
      leaderAliveThreshold: 10s
      leaderElectionDuration: 5s
    pvtData:
      pullRetryThreshold: 60s
      transientstoreMaxBlockRetention: 1000
      pushAckTimeout: 3s
      btlPullMargin: 10
      reconcileBatchSize: 10
      reconcileSleepInterval: 1m
      reconciliationEnabled: true
      skipPullingInvalidTransactionsDuringCommit: false
      implicitCollectionDisseminationPolicy:
        requiredPeerCount: 0
        maxPeerCount: 1
    state:
      enabled: false
      checkInterval: 10s
      responseTimeout: 3s
      batchSize: 10
      blockBufferSize: 20
      maxRetries: 3
  tls:
    enabled: false
    clientAuthRequired: false
    cert:
      file: tls/server.crt
    key:
      file: tls/server.key
    rootcert:
      file: tls/ca.crt
    clientRootCAs:
      files:
        - tls/ca.crt
    clientKey:
      file: null
    clientCert:
      file: null
  authentication:
    timewindow: 15m
  fileSystemPath: /var/hyperledger/production
  BCCSP:
    Default: SW
    SW:
      Hash: SHA2
      Security: 256
      FileKeyStore:
        KeyStore: null
    PKCS11:
      Library: null
      Label: null
      Pin: null
      Hash: null
      Security: null
      SoftwareVerify: null
      Immutable: null
      AltID: null
      KeyIds: null
  mspConfigPath: >-
    crypto-config/peerOrganizations/consignor.trackandtrace.com/peers/peer0.consignor.trackandtrace.com/msp
  localMspId: ConsignorMSP
  client:
    connTimeout: 3s
  deliveryclient:
    blockGossipEnabled: true
    reconnectTotalTimeThreshold: 3600s
    connTimeout: 3s
    reConnectBackoffThreshold: 3600s
    addressOverrides: null
  localMspType: bccsp
  profile:
    enabled: false
    listenAddress: '0.0.0.0:6060'
  handlers:
    authFilters:
      - name: DefaultAuth
      - name: ExpirationCheck
    decorators:
      - name: DefaultDecorator
    endorsers:
      escc:
        name: DefaultEndorsement
        library: null
    validators:
      vscc:
        name: DefaultValidation
        library: null
  validatorPoolSize: null
  discovery:
    enabled: true
    authCacheEnabled: true
    authCacheMaxSize: 1000
    authCachePurgeRetentionRatio: 0.75
    orgMembersAllowedAccess: false
  limits:
    concurrency:
      endorserService: 2500
      deliverService: 2500
      gatewayService: 500
  maxRecvMsgSize: 104857600
  maxSendMsgSize: 104857600
vm:
  endpoint: 'unix:///var/run/docker.sock'
  docker:
    tls:
      enabled: false
      ca:
        file: docker/ca.crt
      cert:
        file: docker/tls.crt
      key:
        file: docker/tls.key
    attachStdout: false
    hostConfig:
      NetworkMode: host
      Dns: null
      LogConfig:
        Type: json-file
        Config:
          max-size: 50m
          max-file: '5'
      Memory: 2147483648
chaincode:
  id:
    path: null
    name: null
  builder: '$(DOCKER_NS)/fabric-ccenv:$(TWO_DIGIT_VERSION)'
  pull: false
  golang:
    runtime: '$(DOCKER_NS)/fabric-baseos:$(TWO_DIGIT_VERSION)'
    dynamicLink: false
  java:
    runtime: '$(DOCKER_NS)/fabric-javaenv:$(TWO_DIGIT_VERSION)'
  node:
    runtime: '$(DOCKER_NS)/fabric-nodeenv:$(TWO_DIGIT_VERSION)'
  externalBuilders:
    - name: ccaas_builder
      path: /opt/hyperledger/ccaas_builder
      propagateEnvironment:
        - CHAINCODE_AS_A_SERVICE_BUILDER_CONFIG
  installTimeout: 300s
  startuptimeout: 300s
  executetimeout: 30s
  mode: net
  keepalive: 0
  system:
    _lifecycle: enable
    cscc: enable
    lscc: enable
    qscc: enable
  logging:
    level: info
    shim: warning
    format: >-
      %{color}%{time:2006-01-02 15:04:05.000 MST} [%{module}] %{shortfunc} ->
      %{level:.4s} %{id:03x}%{color:reset} %{message}
ledger:
  blockchain: null
  state:
    stateDatabase: goleveldb
    totalQueryLimit: 100000
    couchDBConfig:
      couchDBAddress: '127.0.0.1:5984'
      username: null
      password: null
      maxRetries: 3
      maxRetriesOnStartup: 10
      requestTimeout: 35s
      internalQueryLimit: 1000
      maxBatchUpdateSize: 1000
      createGlobalChangesDB: false
      cacheSize: 64
  history:
    enableHistoryDatabase: true
  pvtdataStore:
    collElgProcMaxDbBatchSize: 5000
    collElgProcDbBatchesInterval: 1000
    deprioritizedDataReconcilerInterval: 60m
    purgeInterval: 100
    purgedKeyAuditLogging: true
  snapshots:
    rootDir: /var/hyperledger/production/snapshots
operations:
  listenAddress: '127.0.0.1:9443'
  tls:
    enabled: false
    cert:
      file: null
    key:
      file: null
    clientAuthRequired: false
    clientRootCAs:
      files: []
metrics:
  provider: disabled
  statsd:
    network: udp
    address: '127.0.0.1:8125'
    writeInterval: 10s
    prefix: null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now figured out the answer myself. The problem can appear if you try to create the channel out of your local file system. But in order to create the channel, you have to do it out of the peer network. So in my case I had to enter my docker container with `docker exec -it <container-id> /bin/bash/` first and then run the command.